# Docker Desktop for Windows can't run tagged images

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm trying to do some basic containers in Windows.  I've been using Docker on Linux for years, but this issue is new for me.

Running the command
`docker build -f windowsTest3.df -t dockertest .` results in a good, tagged build.

```
...
 ---> 04064df75127
Step 13/13 : ENTRYPOINT C:/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9e098cff37a2
Successfully built 9e098cff37a2
Successfully tagged dockertest:latest
```

However, attempting to run an interactive shell inside the container gives an error.  `The system cannot find the path specified.`

Edit:  Can't believe I forgot to list the command...
To start the container interactively, I'm running `docker run -it dockertest`, but I've also tried `docker run -it dockertest cmd` and variations of that.

Running `docker images` shows that the tagged image exists, so I can't figure out what's causing the error.

`docker images`

```
C:\Users\devuser.DESKTOP-UV8CO47\Desktop\tmp>docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                    IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dockertest                  latest                 9e098cff37a2        41 minutes ago      12.3GB
```

Here are my path locations:

```
C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.2\common\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\PRQA\PRQA-Framework-2.4.0\common\bin;C:\Users\DevUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.2\arm\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files\nssm-2.24\win64
```

Here is a slightly abridged version of the dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:10.0.17763.316-amd64

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:/tmp/vs_buildtools.exe

# Install Build Tools excluding workloads and components with known issues.
RUN C:/tmp/vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache \
    --installPath C:\BuildTools \
    --all \
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10240 \
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.10586 \
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.14393 \
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK \
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0

ENV chocolateyUseWindowsCompression=false

RUN powershell set-executionpolicy remotesigned

RUN powershell -Command Invoke-Expression ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

RUN powershell -Command Install-PackageProvider -Name chocolatey -Force

RUN powershell -command "choco install -y git"

ENTRYPOINT C:/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat
```

Comment: `attempting to run an interactive shell inside the container gives an error` => which command did you launch to try to do that ? What does your Dockerfile looks like ?

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT  C:/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/VsDevCmd.bat` - Is this path on your host machine or inside the container? Please share the full Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if `VsDevCmd.bat` is available inside the container when it's starting, at `C:/BuildTools/Common7/Tools/` path

Also as per [this Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/manage-windows-dockerfile#considerations-for-using-cmd-with-windows) reference

> On Windows, file paths specified in the CMD instruction must use
>   forward slashes or have escaped backslashes \.
>
> CMD c:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -w

Maybe try your `ENTRYPOINT` like this.

```
ENTRYPOINT C:\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat
```

You can also use `CMD`

```
CMD C:\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat
```

Can also try this as well but recommended is above one

```
ENTRYPOINT C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat
```